# Is it possible to put a big circle on a map using Google Map JavaScript API/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

This is what I currently have:

[image]

I'm looking for something like this (sorry about the ugly circle, imagine it was a perfect circle):

[image]

This is my JavaScript currently:

```
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
}
```

Having it in the center is fine as well since I can just fine tune the coordinates.

Comment: Yes, the Maps API supports Circles. The documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#circles).

Comment: Ever thought about having a look at the documentation? Everything is detailed there, along with examples. Further to that, there are dozens if not hundreds of related questions here about drawing a circle on the map; most of them contain code examples.

Comment: @MrUpsidown sorry couldn't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create circle is possible though `new google.maps.Circle`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Circles</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      async
    ></script>
  </body>
<script>
function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: 37.09, lng: -95.712 },
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  });

    const cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 0.0,
      map,
      center: { lat: 41.878, lng: -87.629 },
      radius: Math.sqrt( 2714856) * 100,
    });
}
</script>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: thanks very much!. your fiddle ain't working though